Display vscode icons in company-tooltip problem
I try to get the vscode (dark or light) icons displayed in the Company tooltip but I have only "abc" in front of the candidates.  I compiled Emacs with rsvg and imagemagick but without success.
Emacs 29.3.50 (build 5, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ version 3.24.33, cairo version 1.16.0
Pop OS 22.04


This indicates that you only have "simple" backends in use in your current buffer (like company-dabbrev, for example). The "abc" icon signifies the text kind. To see more different icons, you'll need to activate some more advanced backend.

I have several backends loaded like company-capf, company-dabbrev-code, company-keywords, company-css and company-tabnine.   What are the advanced backend to activate ?  Can you explain please. :)

company-capf can be that, but you'll need to use something that plugs into it. Like eglot or lsp-mode. company-clang also has support for icons, but unless you work with small projects only, you probably want something LSP-based anyway.
